# IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn in macro

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm trying to write a macro that calls some functions. The functions should only be used by the macro, so I put them inside of a `letfn` wrapping the macro. Pseudocode:

```
(letfn [(fn-a [] ...)
        (fn-b [] ...)
        (fn-c [] (fn-b))]
  (defmacro my-macro [stuff]
   `(let [whatever# (fn-a)]
      (fn-c))))
```

The calls to `fn-a` and `fn-c` work, but when `fn-c` tries to call `fn-b` I get *IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn: #'name.space/fn-b*. Why is that?

If I put `fn-b` and `fn-c` in their own `defn`s, everything works. But I don't want to do that because it isn't clean.

Edit: Just to test, I tried putting the function bindings in the inner `let` but ran into the same exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this can work at all this way.
The call to `fn-c` for example gets expanded to `your.namespace/fn-c`, so your code seems to call other functions that just happen to have the same names.
But you dont have a `your.namespace/fn-b`, which raises the exception.

To refer to a unqualified symbol you need to quote and unquote it: `~'fn-a`
But this won't work either because the local functions aren't defined at the point of expansion, you can only use them for the macro itself.

You either have to define the functions in a namespace and qualify them in the macro or include them in the macroexpansion, which would define them again at each use.

Comment: I tried putting the function bindings in the inner `let` but ran into the same exception. So I don't think `letfn` is at fault. I also am sure these names don't exist elsewhere in the code already.

Comment: If you put them in the inner let, you should use gensym names for them, simply append a pound sign to their names, eg: `fn-a#`. This way the names get auto generated and can't clash with others. If you dont have functions with these names elsewhere i really wonder how any of them could have been called before. If you just want to hide the helper functions, you can make them private to the current namespace/file by using `defn-`

Comment: To generally debug any problem with macros, always look at the expanded code. For this use `macroexpand-1`, `macroexpand` and `clojure.walk/macroexpand-all`

Comment: Btw. It doesn't matter where you put the definitions, if you call them simply by writing their names, these calls still get expanded to namespace qualified names. Use macroexpand and you'll see whats happening. `(macroexpand-1 '(my-macro (stuff...)))`

Comment: I think the cleanest thing that works is to just put the fns inside the macro expansion, so that's what I did. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're after but if I do:

```
(letfn [(fn-a [] (println 1))
        (fn-b [] (println 2))
        (fn-c [] (fn-b))]
  (defmacro my-macro [stuff]  
    `(let [whatever# ~(fn-b)]
       ~(fn-c))))
```

then it works - it just needs the tilde to unquote the function calls.

Both of the following work:

```
(defn fn-x [] (println 1))

(defn fn-y [] (fn-x))

(defmacro my-macro2 [stuff]  
        `(let [whatever# (fn-x)]
           (fn-y)))
```

AND

```
(defn fn-x [] (println 1))

(defn fn-y [] (fn-x))

(defmacro my-macro2 [stuff]  
        `(let [whatever# ~(fn-x)]
           ~(fn-y)))
```

In the first case, the functions are being evaluated and their results incorporated into the macro at compile time whereas in the second they are being evaluated at runtime. With the `letfn` (which is a macro itself) the results are not available at compile time (presumably because they are being compiled after your macro is compiled) so the functions can only be used at runtime.

Comment: Don't you have it backwards? In the first case the functions are being evaluated at runtime, and in the second case at compile time.

I tried putting the function bindings in the inner `let` but ran into the same exception. So I don't think `letfn` is at fault.